# Android update view from async task

Tags: android, animation, asynchronous, view, android-asynctask

This is a little XML animation that I'm trying to get to go off while the app is getting JSON from the server.  It takes about 2 seconds to fetch all the data so I'm trying to show a little loading animation.

The problem I am having is that the images do not change until everything is done and onPostExecute() goes off.

Do I need to pass a view into the AsyncTask or is it something else?

**One last thing** after this AsyncTask completes.  It runs smooth if you run it again.

**XML**

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:oneshot="false">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/loadingtext1" android:duration="100" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/loadingtext2" android:duration="100" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/loadingtext3" android:duration="100" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/loadingtext4" android:duration="100" />
</animation-list>
```

**Code**

```
private class LOGMEIN extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                CRY.CInit(DI, DU, DP);
                publishProgress(0);
                while(data != "whatineed"){
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(450);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                completecheck = 1;
                return "complete";
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                LOADINGTEXT.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation);
                AnimationDrawable LT = (AnimationDrawable) LOADINGTEXT.getBackground();
                LT.start();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                if (result.contentEquals("complete") == true) {
                    domorework();
                } else {
                    finish();
                }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you set onPreExecute() within the AsyncTask?

> protected void onPreExecute() {
>
> //show your animated loader here...
>   progress.show();
>
> }

I use this in onCreate():

Initialize: public ProgressDialog progress;

```
progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
progress.setCancelable(true);
progress.setInverseBackgroundForced(false);
progress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
progress.setMessage("Loading.....");
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the only problem but you are comparing your `String`s wrong in your `loop`.

```
while (data != "whatineed")
```

should be

```
while (!data.equals("whatineed"))
```

or even better would be

```
while (!"whatineed".equals(data))
```

to compare the values instead of the object reference